# How to fix the sidebar similar to bootstrap site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create a sidebar exactly like the one in getbootstrap.com.  I followed the instructions that was on the site and created a sidebar.

But the problem is, it overlaps the footer content. while scrolling the sidebar affixed and the content alone will be scrolled, when it reaches the footer the affix is not removing and yet it overlaps in the footer section.

Could somebody help me solve this bug.

I'm using the following code,

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#leftCol">

    <div role="complementary" id="leftCol">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="125">
              <li><a href="#feature1">Feature1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#feature1">Feature1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#feature1">Feature1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#feature1">Feature1</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm using the following css,

```
 /* Custom Styles */
 ul.nav-tabs {
width: 275px;
margin-top: 30px;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li {
margin: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li:first-child {
border-top: none;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li a {
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 16px;
border-radius: 0;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li.active a, ul.nav-tabs li.active a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: #0088cc;
border: 1px solid #0088cc;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li:first-child a {
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs li:last-child a {
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
 }
 ul.nav-tabs.affix {
top: 30px; /* Set the top position of pinned element */

 }
```

I referred the above code from [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=scrollspy) link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please provide the code for reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED :

**Also don't forgot to load all css and javascript files.**
The code is tested in http://www.tutorialrepublic.com.

Comment: seriously ?? you are supplying two id to one tag!